# CALayer presentationLayer is slow and behind time

Tags: iphone, core-animation, calayer

Scenario:

I have a bunch of moving blocks that move from column 0 to 7. When the user taps, the blocks stop.

Here's my code:

```
- (IBAction)userTap:(id)sender
{
    [block1.layer removeAllAnimations];
    [block2.layer removeAllAnimations];
    [block3.layer removeAllAnimations];
}
```

I now get the presentation layer and extract my essential information:

```
CALayer *player = [block1.layer presentationLayer];
float currentTranslation = [[pLayer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.translation.x"] floatValue];
// Set position of non-moving blocks here
```

currentTranslation is correct, and I've verified it using timing as well. However, it seems that the animation is running faster than my presentationLayer, and so I see a jerk that occurs right when I tap.

What's going on here, and how can I rectify this?

Comment: Are you doing a key frame animation with a paced calculation mode  (`kCAAnimationPaced` or `kCAAnimationCubicPaced`)? I've seen that the presentation layer is off by a lot when you do that. Also, note that the presentation layer only provides provides "a close approximation to the version of the layer that is currently being displayed", _not_ the exact value.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `CADisplayLink` to time the animations to your run loop and overriding `CALayer's` implicit animations with `CATransaction`?

[This blog post covers some of it if not.](http://mysterycoconut.com/blog/2011/09/cag4/)

Comment: CALayer renders itself, I don't think he updated it in his own render loop.